# Android Simple Cursor adapter and Cursor

Tags: android, android-cursor, simplecursoradapter, simplecursortreeadapter

I have build an app that take data with different attribute, adds them in the database and then shows it through a ListView.

I have done the part where data are added, but I Can't figure out how to fetch it(for now I just want the name) from the database and populate it in the ListView.

Here is the part in the database class.

```
public Cursor getCursor() {
    Cursor c = null;
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";
    String where = null;
    c = sqLiteDatabase.query("tbl_customer", new String[]{"Name"}, where, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();

    }
    return c;
}
```

here is the part of code in activity which I want to show the ListView in.

```
private void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = db.getCursor();
   String []From = new String[]{"Name"};

    int [] to = new int[R.id.textView];

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_items,cursor,From,to,0);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ShowDataListView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Please guide me, where I have gone wrong, and correct me.

Comment: so, using the code you posted, is the listview empty?

Comment: I think the problem is. you are fetching "Name" column and using "ESM" as from.

Comment: One thing i would suggest that don't waste time on SimpleCursorAdapter its  deprecated. use loadermanager

Comment: @Vivart that is not the problem, I changed it here to "name" bcuz I wanted it to be more clear for you guys.

Comment: @lino. yes, the Listview is empty.

Comment: ok so can you confirm that (c.getCount > 0). i mean to make sure cursor has some data.

Comment: @Vivart , I would definitely go for loadmanager, but now I want this one work. I have put a lot of effort on this.

Comment: what is `new String[]{"ESM"};`?

Comment: did you see the `logcat` ?

Answer (score 1):

you are using R.id.textView as a size of array

```
int [] to = new int[R.id.textView];
```

it should be like this

```
int [] to = new int[]{R.id.textView};
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to specify the `From` and `To` params of the SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_items,cursor,
new String[] { "Name" },to,0);
```

As for `to`, you need to put the id of your textview from `R.layout.listview_items`. Let's assume the id of your TextView is `R.id.text1` then the adapter will look like following,

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_items,cursor,
new String[] { "Name" },
new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
0);
```

Here, have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int)) to grasp it more clearly.

Comment: tnx for ur answer, but it didn't work.
I keep getting this error:

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: int[] of length 2131230746 would overflow

Comment: In your getCursor method, you should close the database before returning the cursor. 

sqLiteDatabase.close();
return c;

Comment: that was a problem. 
but now I encountered the error that says "the column -id doesn't exist", Although I have a column ID, I tried to change the "ID" to "-id" and upgrade the database by changing its version but it seems that I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Drop the schema all together and create a new schema with refined column naming. See if its works.